# Adding "_" in front/after a variable name for built in functions and shadow names

Tags: python

I have the following example:

```
def get_max_close(symbol): # Example 1
    df = pd.read_csv("../../ml4t/data/{}.csv".format(symbol))
    get_max = df["Close"].max()
    res = {symbol: float(get_max)}
    return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    symbol = ["AAPL", "IBM"] # Example 2
    max_close = {"Max": [get_max_close(s) for s in symbol]}
    print max_close
```

My example 1 shows the following issue:

```
This inspection detects shadowing names defined in outer scopes
```

Example 2 is the outer scope variable with the same name. I don't want to change the code and I recall reading in one of the PEPs that I can add a `_` to this variable to make it work.

I also recall reading that placement of the `_` matters (in the same way that camel casing matters in functions).

I believe placing the `_` before the variable name (ie. `_symbol`) is the correct way of achieving this. Placing it after would be exclusively for when I have a variable with the same name as a built in function (ie. `dict_`).

Am I mixing these two up? And could you provide me the url to the related pep? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing you need to fix here. It is just a warning from your IDE, *not Python*.

The IDE is pointing out that the name `symbol` is used both as a global (in the `__name__ == '__main__'` block), and as a local in the `get_max_close()` function. This is *fine* and not something you need to be concerned about.

The advice is aimed at using names that are provided by Python itself,  the *built-in* names, like `list`, `id`, `str` or `all`. You can then rename your variable to `id_` or `all_` and not run the risk of trying to use the built-in as well. That's simply not the case here.

If you used the name `_symbol`, then by convention you are signalling that the name is considered private to your implementation (e.g. anyone using your code should not rely on the name existing in the same form in future versions).

You could use a different name altogether too, you don't *have* to use `symbol_`. I'd just stick to `symbol`, it is a perfectly valid name for the local, and the IDE is being overzealous here.

The PEP you are thinking of is [PEP 8 – *Style Guide for Python Code*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which in the [*Naming Styles* section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) states:

> - `_single_leading_underscore`: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. `from M import *` does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.
> - `single_trailing_underscore_`: used by convention to avoid conflicts with Python keyword, e.g.
>
>   ```
>   Tkinter.Toplevel(master, class_='ClassName')
>   ```